# when will a UK-published English translation of a Chilean novel reach the public domain in USA

Tags: copyright, public-domain

I'm a US  ebook publisher looking for out of print books which might be in the public domain which I can digitize. I found a novel which I'd like to investigate.

- It was originally published in Spanish in Chile in 1928.
- The author died in 1946.
- The book was translated into English by two British translators and
  published in UK by a fairly well known publishing house in 1931.
- As far as I know, the book was never published in USA. I am assuming
  there was no copyright registration but I can say definitively that
  are no copyright renewal registrations  in the US.
- I have no idea when the British translators died. How does one find
  out?

(The work in question is THE PARTNER by Jenaro Prieto "English version by Blanca De Roig and Guy Dowler")

I'm still doing research, but there's a chance that neither the work nor the translation was ever published in USA.

What would be the guidelines for determining when something with these characteristics can be public domain in the US?

Also, suppose that I learn that the translation was eventually  published in USA, (let's say in 1938), but the copyright on the copyright translation on that work  was never renewed in the US. Would that affect the year when this work goes into the public domain in USA?

Finally I realize that my question is specific to one book, but are there resources helpful for determining copyright status of translated works? THanks.